# Use define as you get function data return

Tags: php, html, database, function, variables

i am getting some html code from database. It will be stored with few PHP defines. which are defined in a previous function where the current function will return the html code from database.

How can i get the define value inside the html code revived from database.

The defines you see has been declared in the data which i am getting from database. But i am unable to get their values. It is not dynamically getting the define value in $thankYouTemplate

```
function newPostPageMailDesign($title, $feturedImage, $smallContent, $permalink, $youMayAlsoLikeQuery) {

define('featuredImage', $feturedImage);
define('shortContent', $smallContent);
define('permalink', $permalink);
define('title', $title);

$thankYouTemplate = getData();
$HtmlAMiler = $thankYouTemplate;
    return $HtmlAMiler;
}
function getData()
{
$Data = "Some HTML Code from database with".featuredImage.permalink."already in the databse";
return $Data;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear to me. You already got the HTML string in `$thankYouTemplate = getData();`

Comment: @Cid The defines you see has been declared in the data which i am getting from database. But i am unable to get their values. It is not dynamically getting the define value in $thankYouTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your HTML code in your database by adding a dummy string e.g "__DUMMYSTRING__". Now using **str_replace** replace the "__DUMMYSTRING__" with the content or HTML Code you wish to add.

example:

`echo str_replace( '__DUMMYSTRING__' , $newHTMLCODE, $HTMLCodeFormDataBase);`

May not be the efficient way but may work.